# Qt QStatusBar wider separator

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, statusbar

I am using qt to develop an embedded gui application. I am using 2 QStatusBars to make a menu-like buttons one can see on an osciloscope for example:

[image]

My problem is I dont know a proper way of separating the buttons from eachother with a certain width. In the picture you can see I have added couple separators to achieve that, but it doesnt look that way when run on the target.

Is there a better way to separate buttons on QStatusBar with certain width?

Comment: What about QSpacerItem or simply, a blanc QWidget ?

Comment: indeed use a QSpacerItem

Comment: how do you add spacer between 2 widgets in a status bar? @UmNyobe

Comment: @Martin I dont know how to insert QSpacerItem in a status bar.

Comment: @Martin doing so will give you error saying; cannot convert argument 1 from 'QSpacerItem*' to 'QWidget*'

Comment: @NanaOsaberima yeap, you're right, I deleted my comment so. Use layout.addSpacerItem(...) function.

Comment: @Martin putting the widgets and the spacerItem in the status bar through a layout also gives you error saying status bar already has a layout.

Comment: So if there is already a layout in there, use this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer you use a blank widget to do the seperation as suggested by Martin, like so;

```
//the 2 widgets in the status bar
button1 = new QPushButton("Button1");
button2 = new QPushButton("Button2");

//the blank widget. You can set your width with 'setFixedWidth(int)'
widget = new QWidget;
widget->setFixedWidth(50);
widget->setHidden(1);
widget->setVisible(1);

//placing them in the status bar
statusBar = new QStatusBar;
statusBar->addWidget(button1);
statusBar->addWidget(widget);
statusBar->addWidget(button2);
```